# Can a bitmap point to another bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a bitmap downloader class which decodes a stream into a Bitmap object.

Can I do something like

```
Bitmap bitmap;

bitmap = object;
```

when I do `imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` 
would be the same as  `imageview.setImageBitmap(object)`

Also, is it posible to create multiple instances of bitmap?    like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();  // how to do this? 
    new BitmapDownloaderAsynctask(bitmap).execute(url); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I do imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap) would be the same as imageview.setImageBitmap(object)

Yes, it would be the same (as long as `object` is another instance of `Bitmap`)

In order to create `Bitmap` manually, there is a bunch of static methods [Bitmap.createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.util.DisplayMetrics,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) exist to create bitmaps ([Bitmap class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html))

As an example, here is the easiest way to create a bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888); //100*100 bitmap in ARGB color space
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to keep bitmap reference unchanged, you need to decode stream in a separate bitmap and then copy content of this bitmap into your original bitmapHolder. You can do that by drawing on the canvas:

AsyncTask code:

.....

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapHolder); //this bitmap was passed to AsyncTask
Bitmap tmpBitmap = Bitmap.decodeStream(...);

canvas.drawBitmap(tmpBitmap, 0, 0, null); //this will copy your decoded bitmap into your original bitmap which was passed into AsyncTask
```

.....

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.   So if I create a bitmap object,  and add it to an ArrayList (for the adapter)  AND ALSO add it to my DownloaderAsyncTask,   when the asynctask is finished, my bitmap object points to the bitmap I downloaded, and since the arraylist has a reference of it too,   i could get the bitmap directly from the arraylist, right?

Comment: well, it is possible to implement everything like you describe:) It depends how your AsyncTask operates with the bitmap passed into it. If your AsyncTask creates its own Bitmap to decode the stream, you need to copy bitmap content to your original bitmap. If AsyncTask writes directly to the bitmap passed, then everything should be ok as is

Comment: My AsyncTask creates a bitmap in this instruction:  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);  the input stream is from an URL. That bitmap object works perfectly if I do imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);     the problem is that for each URL I want to send a 'bitmap holder' to the asynctask  so  I can do something like     this.bitmapHolder = bitmap;   on the onPostExcecute.   bitmapHolder was also sent to an ArrayList<Bitmap>   which is sent to the ArrayAdapter     so i can do something like     savedBitmap = arraylist.get(position);  and set it to the imageview. is it possible?

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you need to copy your decoded content into bitmap holder rather than overwriting it's pointer. So if you passed bitmapHolder to your AsyncTask (which also sits in your ArrayList), you need to decode stream in separate bitmap (`Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream`), and in your AsyncTask copy content of this bitmap in your bitmapHolder. I'll update my answer with the code